# Decending Order Heap Sort

Tags: c, sorting, heap, heapsort

I've been trying to learn how to implement a heapsort.

In particular, I have a heapsort algorithm which sorts the input in acending order,
but i can't figure out what needs to be changed to make it decending order.

Here is the code: (Some of this is from the textbook)

```
void heapSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{
  int i, temp;

  for (i = (array_size / 2); i >= 0; i--)
    siftDown(numbers, i, array_size - 1);

  for (i = array_size-1; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    temp = numbers[0];
    numbers[0] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = temp;
    siftDown(numbers, 0, i-1);
  }
}


void siftDown(int numbers[], int root, int bottom)
{
  int done, maxChild, temp;

  done = 0;
  while ((root*2 <= bottom) && (!done))
  {
    if (root*2 == bottom)
      maxChild = root * 2;
    else if (numbers[root * 2] > numbers[root * 2 + 1])
      maxChild = root * 2;
    else
      maxChild = root * 2 + 1;

    if (numbers[root] < numbers[maxChild])
    {
      temp = numbers[root];
      numbers[root] = numbers[maxChild];
      numbers[maxChild] = temp;
      root = maxChild;
    }
    else
      done = 1;
  }
}
```

If anyone could point out what portion of the code needs to be changed, that would be extremely helpful :).

Comment: Hint: how are you determining which element should go before another one? Change that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i was only changing one place in siftDown. Once i changed the if else and the swap part of the function it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have implemented is a "max heap" (i.e. the values of the children of each node are smaller than the value of the parent node). You need to just change the `siftDown` function so that the parent is always the smaller than the children.

This makes it a min-heap and serves up the values in reverse order (since the smallest elements are getting to the top of the heap first), thus giving you a descending order sort.

Comment: Thanks, my only problem was I was only changing one spot in siftDown.